# HTML table rows custom sort using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, html-table

I am sorting my table rows on a `Code/SKU` column.  `Code/SKU` column may or may not contain the `-` (dash) which is my delimiter. The 3 digit code after `-` is my product rack number with a prefix between A-Z. I am trying to sort the products in an ascending order based on the rack number `irrespective of the prefix`. In case if the rack number is missing those products should be listed on the top.

For example, if the **input** `Code/SKU` column contains:

```
RIN65631-A24
PNT64705
CPC31378-D06
```

Then the **output** `Code/SKU column` should be sorted as:

```
PNT64705
CPC31378-D06
RIN65631-A24
```

**Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivamsurve/rn6JR/2/)**

I am getting the desired output as stated above but if you look at my JSFiddle you will see that I am using multiple calls `$(this).find()` function to retrieve a particular element from the DOM which IMO is not necessary. There may be a better way to avoid the redundant find() calls and achieve the same output. Can someone help me in this regard?

**EDIT:**

**Note:** Sorting should be performed on the DOM ready event.

Comment: Have you thought about using something like https://datatables.net to do your sorting? You can also intercept the sorting event on that particular column and do something different.

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble Thank you for the suggestion but the datatables.net plugin will sort the elements on "Alpha Numeric" value of `Code/SKU`  whereas the requirement is to custom sort on `just the numeric part` of the rack number in Code/SKU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sortContent](https://github.com/abdennour/jquery.sortContent) jquery PLugin :

```
 $('td.sku').sortContent({asc:true,
                         target:function(e){
                           return $(e).parent();
                         },helper:function(e){
                            var html=$(e).html().split('-'); 
                            if(html.length===2){return html[1]}
                             else {return ''}    
                          }
 });
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/rn6JR/4/)

**Explanation**

- *target callbak* :  You sort according `td` element , However, `tr` should be sorted . So the target is `tr` which is the parent of `td` element.
- *helper* : to identify the content to sort

**UPDATE :**

to sort just numeric characters, Helper callback should be as following :

```
var myhelper=function(e){
   var html=$(e).html().split('-'); 
    if(html.length===2){return 'b'+html[1].numeric()}
    else {return 'a'+html[0].numeric()}

};
```

See [Demo v2](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/rn6JR/9/)

Comment: First of all I do not want any "Sort IT" button on my page to trigger the sorting. The data is already loaded in the DOM and that's the one I want to sort using jQuery.

Comment: Secondly, your sort function does not yield the desired output. It's sorting the elements on "Alpha Numeric" value of my rack number whereas the requirement is to sort on `just the numeric part of that rack number`.  Please check my input and output in the question.

Comment: Thta's exactly I wanted. Appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var th = jQuery('.shortid'),
    inverse = false;

th.click(function(){

    var header = $(this),
        index = header.index();

    header
        .closest('.right-contacts-details')
        .find('.shorting')
        .filter(function(){
            return $(this).index() === index;
        })
        .sort(function(a, b){

            a = $(a).text();
            b = $(b).text();

            return (
                isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) ?
                    a > b : +a > +b
                ) ?
                    inverse ? -1 : 1 :
                    inverse ? 1 : -1;

        }, function(){
            return this.parentNode;
        });

    inverse = !inverse;

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Use KnockoutJS. You get the feature out of the box.